# Best practice for caching images read from an inputstream in Java

Tags: java

I have a servlet that acts as a proxy for fetching images by reading the images as bytes off a HttpURLConnection input stream and then writing the bytes to the response output stream.  Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
  out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
```

I would like to start caching the image in the proxy servlet.  I'm considering wrapping the byte array and storing in a Map but I suspect there is a better way.   I've noticed the javax.imagio package but I have no experience with it and not sure if its relevant here.  Specifically, I am looking for thoughts on how to store the image and not so much the mechanics of caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only caching the images, I would recommend keeping the image as a byte array, not as an image. Using imageio to read the image would uncompress the images and they would take much more memory space.

The class WeekHashMap is probably the easiest way to cache things but you have little control on the way entries are evicted from it.

Comment: This is NOT a good use of `WeakHashMap`. Please see http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/09/weakhashmap-is-not-cache-understanding.html for an explanation of why not. Hint: Your values will disappear as soon as nobody is holding a reference to your keys.

Answer (score 2):

In some limited cases, a hash map could work. But you need to think about:

(1) How you're going to purge cached images from memory when the cache gets "full" (however you define that -- probably some maximum amount of memory that you want to devote to caching).
(2) How you're going to deal with concurrency.
(3) Relatedly, how you're going to deal with the case where client A requests an image, and then client B requests the same image while it is still being loaded into the cache for client A.

A very simple solution to (1) could be to always store SoftReferences to the image data and let the JVM take care of deciding when to purge them (bearig in mind it could arbitrarily purge them at times beyond your control). Otherwise, you need to develop some kind of policy (first in, image accessed longest ago, smallest/largest image etc, image that will take longest to decode if we have to load it again etc)-- only you know your data and usage, so you have to find the right policy.

For (2), [ConcurrentHashMap](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_hashmap2.shtml) will generally help you out; you may decide to use explicit locks and other concurrency utilities in fancier cases.

For (3), a fairly elegant solution proposed by Goetz et al is to hijack the Future class. In your map, you store a Future to the cached object (or to your "cache entry" object). If a requester finds that a Future has already been added to the map, then it can call get() and wait for the other thread to finish caching the data. (You could achieve a similar effect with an explicit lock and condition, but Future takes some of the work out for you.)

P.S. I agree with the poster who said you probably want to store the images in their original coded form. But from your code I'm assuming that was probably what you were intending all along.